# Creating map book via ArcGIS data driven pages with a dynamic table (graphic table element) falling outside of layout extent

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, dynamic-tables

I am using ArcGIS to create a map book that is data driven and has a dynamic table (graphic table element) associated to each page. The data driven page is indexed to follow a line for its extent. Each extent has a different number of points that are represented through the dynamic table. The question I may ask is, is there a way I can export the maps to pdf to include parts of the table that might fall outside of the layout extent (rollover) on a separate page?

Answer (score 1):

To do this I think you would need to use ArcPy rather than the ArcMap GUI.

I recommend that you start by trying to export a single layout in a map that does not have Data Driven Pages enabled to create the multi-page PDF that you seek.

Once you can do that just add iteration through the index layer that you would normally use for Data Driven Pages.